# Show plot legends for multiple curves in one plot

Tags: plotting, legending, graphics

I have 5 curves, figure1a0, figure1a001, figure1a01,  figure1ae01, and figure1ae001,.  I display all these curves in one plot with `Show`. I want to give a label to each curve, How I do this?

I tried

```
Show[ {figure1a0, figure1a001 , figure1a01,  figure1ae01, figure1ae001 }, 
  LegendLabel -> {1, 1, 1, 1, 1} ]
```

but it does not work

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: [`PlotLegends`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLegends.html)

Answer (score 9):

```
points = Table[{x, .5 x^2 - 3 + RandomReal[]}, {x, -3, 3}]; 
Show[{ListPlot[points, PlotLegends -> {"Experiment"}], 
          Plot[{.5 x^2 - 3}, {x, -3, 3}, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotLegends -> {"Model"}]}]
```

[image]